# Is it possible to have android UiAutomator in background and pass arguments to it to perform actions?

Tags: android, ui-automation

My problem is I want to execute some UI actions with UiAutomator (at least I don't know any other method), but running shell commands like

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.myproject.TestClass#testMethod com.myproject.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

for each action takes too long to load up the class and execute. I assume that I can maybe start the test and have it running and waiting for some event and then pass some parameters so that it will execute my actions.